# Is 100 a magic number for cardinality estimation of SELECT * FROM [Multi-Statement-Table-Valued-Function] queries?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, user-defined-functions, sql-server-2019, cardinality-estimation

I'm running on SQL Server 2019. Whenever I write a query of the form

```
SELECT * 
FROM [Multi-Statement-Table-Valued-Function]
```

the execution plan shows that it expected to get 100 rows from this process. Is this a consistent and documented pattern? Or is it just a quirk of my server?

I have a set of notes on cardinality estimation from SQL Server 2014 and I'm confident that the estimation methods haven't changed since 2014, but they make no mention of this magic number.

Comment: You're on 2019 but what compat level are you in? See https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/5728/sql-server-multi-statement-table-value-function-mtvfs-performance-difference-between-versions/ for example. (Also, just rewrite your functions as inline.)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Whatever the default is. I'm certain that won't have been changed.

Comment: The "default" depends on whether you installed 2019 fresh or upgraded over time, and whether you created the database fresh or restored from some older source.

Comment: In that case you should be looking at actual execution plans rather than estimated anyway because it will be recompiled after the MSTVF table variable is populated

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> MSTVFs have a fixed cardinality guess of “100” in SQL Server 2014 and
> SQL Server 2016, and “1” for earlier versions

[Source](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/sql-server-blog/introducing-interleaved-execution-for-multi-statement-table/ba-p/385417)

Later versions (compatibility level >= SQL Server 2017) have interleaved execution which is also discussed in that source.

Testing in 2022 the `100` estimate is still used as an initial estimate when getting an "estimated" plan - but the interleaved execution means that this plan will be replaced.

One other relevant passage from the above article is

> **How does interleaved execution work for consecutive executions?**
>
> Once an interleaved execution plan is cached, the plan with the
> revised estimates on the first execution is used for consecutive
> executions without re-instantiating interleaved execution.

Comment: I would have preferred official documentation to an official blog, but I can't do any better than you have.

Comment: It was definitely extensively trailed when the change was made - might be mentioned in the "new cardinality estimator" docs

Comment: yep. "The default fixed cardinality estimate for multi-statement table-valued functions in the new CE is now 100 instead of 1" - in "Optimizing Your Query Plans with the SQL Server 2014 Cardinality Estimator" white paper